# SharePoint Online Link navigation to server location

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a solution to link my site hub navigation to a server location (local file server).

I've tried everything, seems that pasting the path does not seem to work.
Shortcuts fail as well...

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop shortcut to a My site link(**http://domain/my/person.aspx**) using Firefox, Chrome or Internet Explorer (IE).

**Steps to create a shortcut to a web link**

1) Go to your my site link using Firefox, Chrome or Internet Explorer (IE)

2) Resize your browser so that you can see the browser and your desktop

3) Click into the URL address bar and drag the drop it to your desktop. This creates the shortcut into your location

4)Rename the shortcut to whatever name you want and place it into your shared location.

**Note:** You should remove your name or email(if any) in the url before drag and drop the url into desktop

Comment: If the above answer is satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use? If you use IE, you can try adding URLs to the trusted site.

In addition, web browsers consider it a security violation for a web site to link to a 
local file. They don't like web sites interacting with the local file system at all.

My best suggestion would be to upload the files to a document library and then link to these files from your list.